# How to make nested dict comprehensions in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, dictionary-comprehension

I have double for-loop and I would like to reformat it to dict comprehensions:

```python
tests = {'var1': {'L': True, 'C': True},
         'var2': {'L': False, 'C': True},
         'var3': {'L': False, 'C': False}}

for feat, tags in tests.iteritems():
    for name, value in tags.iteritems():
        if value is True:
            print '{}, {}'.format(name, feat))
            obj = create_obj(type=name)
            run_method(feat, obj)
```

Should be easy?

Comment: You aren't creating a new dictionary; there's no use for a dict comprehension here.

Comment: I see, so I misunderstood list/dict comprehension, but if i leave only print statemant, it's working as @Kasramvd mention.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are printing a string you can use a list comprehension like following:

```
['{}, {}'.format(name, feat) for feat, tags in tests.iteritems() for name, value in tags.iteritems() if value]
```

And if you want to create a key-value pair from `name` and `feat` you can use a dict comprehension:

```
{name:feat for feat, tags in tests.iteritems() for name, value in tags.iteritems() if value}
```

Comment: and if I want execute some method instead of print: run_method(name, value)?

Comment: @emcek What you mean by executing some method? does it returns anything? if it returns a value you can replace `'{}, {}'.format(name, feat)` with your attribute which has been called like (`my_attr()`) if not it would be none.